# DB2 ignore errors on variable length

Tags: sql, db2, parameter-passing

I wrote a lot of parametrized queries where parameters are inserted by the user. If the user inserts strings longer than the field where parametrized value is referring to, DB2 throws a SQL0302N error.

There is a way to avoid it?

Example:

```
Create Table Foo (Code Char(3) Not Null, Descr Varchar(50));

PreparedStatement ps = new PreparedStatement(
    "Select * From Foo Where Code = ? Or Descr = ?");
ps.setString(1, txtInput.value);
ps.setString(1, txtInput.value);
```

If the parametrized value is bigger than 3 characters then first parameter throws an exception.

The use of «= TRIM(?)» or «Like ?» instead of «= ?» avoids the error.
But I'd like fix it  modifyng the connection string. In this way I will be sure that error won't thrown any more, even if I forget to fix some queries.

Comment: Why not perform the string length validation (or truncation) in your application code?

Comment: Because it is ugly, and not usefull. I used some thousand of setSrting() in my project, (without considering the use of setObject because the parameter is parametrized and undefined). I found only few times where it  was dangerous, but I'd like to be sure that dont catch the error.